# Unity2D C# Randomly Spawn GameObject in an Area over another GameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

I'm new to Unity2D (Unity 5.0.2f1) and have been searching for a solution which I'm sure is staring me in the face!

I have a game object (essentially a road) like below (DirtTrack1):

[image]

I have a spawner which spawns GameObjects (vehicles). I want to spawn those vehicles over this road.

I have tried the following code to do this, essentially trying to spawn the vehicle within the Y-axis area of the road by getting the bottom Y co-ordinate of the road and the top Y co-ordinate, so I get the min and max vertical positions of where I can place the vehicle:

```
void FixedUpdate() {

    // Repeat spawning after the period spawn
    // route has finished.
    if (!_inSpawningIteration)
        StartCoroutine (SpawnVehiclePeriodically());
}

IEnumerator SpawnVehiclePeriodically()   
{
        // First, get the height of the vehicle and road.
        float vehicleHeightHalf = vehiclePreFab.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().bounds.size.y / 2f;
        float roadHeightHalf = roadObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().bounds.size.y / 2f;

        float roadTopY = roadObject.transform.position.y + roadHeightHalf;
        float roadBottomY = roadObject.transform.position.y - roadHeightHalf;

        // Next, ensure that maxY is within bounds of this farm vehicle.
        roadMaxY = roadTopY - vehicleHeightHalf;
        roadMinY = roadBottomY + vehicleHeightHalf;

    // Set the position and spawn.
    Vector3 newPosition = new Vector3 (Const_RoadItemsPositionX, randomY, 0f);
    GameObject vehicle = (GameObject)GameObject.Instantiate (vehiclePreFab, newPosition, Quaternion.identity);
}
```

This does spawn randomly but most times it is always not within the road itself. It is either part on the road or at the outside edge of it.

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here but I'm sure it is something very simple!

Comment: float roadY = roadObject.transform.localPosition.y; shouldn't be roadObject.transform.position.y?

Comment: That didn't seem to make much difference. My vehicle is still coming up on the edge of the boundary. See here...http://imgur.com/a/GEX6S

Comment: You mean in the X coordinate? because that is controlled by your Const_RoadItemsPositionX constant

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant.

Comment: Maybe make Const_RoadItemsPositionX smaller? I don't know what is that constant, the code you posted is only for the Y axis

Comment: But why would the X position be an issue? It's the Y positioning that is giving me a problem. The vehicle always starts correctly from X. (BTW Const_RoadItemsPositionX is 5.05f).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136020/discussion-between-juan-bayona-beriso-and-ashestoashes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tick the kinematic check of your vehicle, physics may be moving it out of the road if you don't do that.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time out to help this one. I will make sure all the GOs that I control movement by script over have this applied.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `localPosition`. From [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-localPosition.html):

> Position of the transform relative to the parent transform.
>
> If the transform has no parent, it is the same as `Transform.position`.

Looking at your scene, your road has a parent object and the relative position you are getting might be messing up with the spawn position of cars.

Comment: I actually don't need that road to be in the parent - it was just a logical grouping I made. I moved the road out to the root so it does not have a parent but the problem is still there. Take a look at where the vehicle is spawning here: http://imgur.com/a/GEX6S